# Constructing peculiar dictionary out of file (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to automaticaly form a `dictionary` from files that have the following structure.

```
str11 str12 str13
str21 str22
str31 str32 str33 str34
...
```

that is, two, three or four strings each line, with spaces in between. The dictionary I'd like to construct out of this list must have following structure:

```
{str11:(str12,str13),str21:(str22),str31:(str32,str33,str34), ... }
```

(that is, all entries `str*1` are the keys -- all of them different -- and the remaining ones are the `values`). What can I use?

Comment: Is there any duplicate records in the first column?

Comment: No, they are all different. Thanks for asking. I'll include that.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> with open('abc') as f:
...     dic = {}
...     for line in f:
...         key, val = line.split(None,1)
...         dic[key] = tuple(val.split())
...         
>>> dic
{'str31': ('str32', 'str33', 'str34'),
 'str21': ('str22',),
 'str11': ('str12', 'str13')}
```

If you want the order of items to be preserved then consider using [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> with open('abc') as f:
        dic = OrderedDict()
        for line in f:
            key, val = line.split(None,1)
            dic[key] = tuple(val.split())
...         
>>> dic
OrderedDict([
('str11', ('str12', 'str13')),
('str21', ('str22',)),
('str31', ('str32', 'str33', 'str34'))
])
```

Comment: Is `len(dic['str21'])` 1 or 2?

Comment: It's 1; the `(foo,)` syntax means a single-element tuple

Comment: @ASGM It is 1, a tuple with one element has a trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `StringIO` instance for simplicity:

```
import io
fobj = io.StringIO("""str11 str12 str13
str21 str22
str31 str32 str33 str34""")
```

One line does the trick:

```
>>> {line.split(None, 1)[0]: tuple(line.split()[1:]) for line in fobj}
{'str11': ('str12', 'str13'),
 'str21': ('str22',),
 'str31': ('str32', 'str33', 'str34')}
```

Note the `line.split(None, 1)`. This limits the splitting to one item because we have to use `.split()` twice in a dict comprehension. We cannot store intermediate results for reuse as in a loop. The `None` means split at any whitespace.

For an `OrderedDict` you can also get away with one line using a generator expression:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

>>> OrderedDict((line.split(None, 1)[0], tuple(line.split()[1:])) 
                 for line in fobj)
OrderedDict([('str11', ('str12', 'str13')), ('str21', ('str22',)),
             ('str31', ('str32', 'str33', 'str34'))])
```